# How do i retrieve the note like B4, C5 etc from AudiFileInspector from NAudio

Tags: midi, naudio

```
1:1:0 0 NoteOn Ch: 1 B4 Vel:96 Len: 473

1:2:0 480 NoteOn Ch: 1 B4 Vel:96 Len: 473

1:3:0 960 NoteOn Ch: 1 C5 Vel:96 Len: 473
```

This is what they print out. What I'm looking for is the splitting of data up. I could get the absolute time, but not the value such as `B4`, `C5` and the `Len: value`, which is 473(varies from different songs)

http://naudio.codeplex.com/downloads/get/523321

Answer (score 1):

It's open source, so you can examine the code in [MidiFileInspector.cs](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AudioFileInspector/FileInspectors/MidiFileInspector.cs), and see that it is just making use of `NoteEvent.ToString` which in turn makes use of the [`NoteEvent.NoteName`](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudio/Midi/NoteEvent.cs) property.